# print from android using wifi or bluetooth

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, wifi, offline

I am making an app in which i require printing options in Android. I tried with google cloud print and other options, but my requirement is that i need to print it offline either by using a network wifi or bluetooth. I have no idea in this field and also android doesnt come with inbuilt print options  ...so please help

my basic requirement is that my device should first find printer either in a network or some way through bluetooth and then print should b fired..

Please help and thanks in advise I really need some starting knowledge to begin with

any other suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Some bluetooth printers use OBEX for file transfer (Polaroid, for example), but android has no api to use it except sharing api. You can create your own implementation of OBEX or google it.